# OpenOffice Calc: Is it possible to create conditional formatting to highlight a row based on checkmarks?

Tags: conditional-formatting, openoffice, openoffice-calc

This is kind of a two-part question.

1. Is it possible to create conditional formatting to highlight an entire row with a certain color based on whether the checkmark object in the row is selected? For instance, in the example below, if "Rename URL?" is selected for a certain row, the whole row would be changed to a different color.
2. Assuming the above is possible, is it possible to go one step further and have different colors override each other if subsequent objects are checked off in the same row? For instance (again, referring to the example photo below): If "Rename URL?" is checked, the whole row would be orange. But if "Redirect Built" is checked, it would override that and color the whole row yellow. If "Page Built" is checked, it would recolor the whole row green.

[Example Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKdrV.jpg)

I'm kind of at a loss on this one, so any help you can provide would be very much appreciated!